# Joomla Component adds underscore automatically

Tags: php, javascript, joomla, joomla2.5

This is a weird issue I ran into. Most likely something I am missing but after a few hours and searching over 200 files, I cannot find ANY reason for this to happen (yet it is anyway).

The amazing problem is that I have an override created for com_finder, I am doing this because you can only setup com_finder in one context and the site I am working on needs 2. So I copied com_finder and renamed it to com_finderhmg and did some find and replace to make it work exactly the same, just a different name and its own db tables.

Anyway it loads up fine but when I go to index I get a JS error from mootools, it basically says that a dom element does not exist (finderhmg-progress-container). Looking in the file i see that it is indeed there, but only in the source file, when I view source on the page it shows up as finder_hmg-progress-container.

Anyone else have this happen to them before? Or a something I might just be missing without realizing?

Here is the source file

```
<div id="finderhmg-indexer-container">
    <br /><br />
    <h1 id="finderhmg-progress-header"><?php echo JText::_('COM_FINDERHMG_INDEXER_HEADER_INIT'); ?></h1>

    <p id="finderhmg-progress-message"><?php echo JText::_('COM_FINDERHMG_INDEXER_MESSAGE_INIT'); ?></p>

    <form id="finderhmg-progress-form"></form>

    <div id="finderhmg-progress-container"></div>

    <input id="finderhmg-indexer-token" type="hidden" name="<?php echo JFactory::getSession()->getFormToken(); ?>" value="1" />
</div>
```

And the view source

```
<div id="finder_hmg-indexer-container">
    <br /><br />
    <h1 id="finder_hmg-progress-header">Starting Indexer</h1>

    <p id="finder_hmg-progress-message">The indexer is being initialized. Do not close this window.</p>

    <form id="finder_hmg-progress-form"></form>

    <div id="finder_hmg-progress-container"></div>

    <input id="finder_hmg-indexer-token" type="hidden" name="95b922cc6e0f81d18fd1e23e75a09d5f" value="1" />
</div>
```

There is no other file for the indexer, at least not that I know of (mass search of pretty much all of joomla yielded nothing).

Answer (score 0):

This is very strange. However let's look at it the other way around. If your component outputs the code correctly, there can be only one piece of code that can change it, and that's a plugin (either a content plugin or a system plugin).

Try disabling all 3rd party content or system plugins until you find the one responsible for this behaviour.

Comment: Yea I have started looking through them, I do know there is a finder group in general but have yet to see anything that relates to it. It needs the plugins to get to the place with the error though, so I cannot disable, only review the code.

Comment: well if you disable and the error is gone, at least you can identify the offending plugin and do a code review of that alone

Comment: I will look into it further when I get the time, thanks for your input.